# Trying to echo a YouTube URL into an iframe in PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to make a simple page that displays a certain video I add into a variable at the top for each day in a week (monday, tuesdays etc.) However, if I hardcode the YouTube URL into the iFrame, that works. But if I pass in a variable, it doesn't.

iFrame won't show with a variable in the 'src' attribute.

```
<?php
$monday = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnPkmozi7Zc";
$tuesday = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnPkmozi7Zc";
$wednesday = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnPkmozi7Zc";
$thursday = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnPkmozi7Zc";
$friday = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnPkmozi7Zc";
$saturday = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnPkmozi7Zc";
$sunday  = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnPkmozi7Zc";

$dayofweek = date("w");

switch ($dayofweek) {
    case 1:
        $videoUrl = $monday;
        break;
    case 2:
        $videoUrl = $tuesday;
        break;
    case 3:
        $videoUrl = $wednesday;
        break;
    case 4:
        $videoUrl = $thursday;
        break;
    case 5:
        $videoUrl = $friday;
        break;
    case 6:
        $videoUrl = $saturday;
        break;
    case 0:
        $videoUrl = $sunday;
        break;
}
?>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo $monday; ?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you echoing `$monday` instead of `$videoUrl`?

Comment: Just to see if it rendered any of the other variables, but it didn't. Doesn't work with `$videoUrl` neither.

Comment: So when you inspect the element what is inside the `src` attribute?

Comment: It outputs the YouTube URL. The URL is correct, but the iFrame is still invisible. So the code loads itself when I view source, but not showing in the browser itself. Just a blank page.

Comment: Ok then it isn't a problem with PHP it is a problem with the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have embed link, like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/{video_id}
```

This link you can find in youtube in section share

Comment: Of course. That's why it worked previously. I just copied an example, and I totally forgot that it doesn't use normal YouTube URLs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $links = array(
        '0' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/rnPkmozi7Zc', //Sunday
        '1' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/rnPkmozi7Zc', //Monday
        '2' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/rnPkmozi7Zc', //Tuesday
        '3' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/rnPkmozi7Zc', //Wednesday
        '4' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/rnPkmozi7Zc', //Thursday
        '5' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/rnPkmozi7Zc', //Friday
        '6' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/rnPkmozi7Zc', //Saturday
    );

    $numeric_day = date("w");

    $url_to_load = $links[$numeric_day];
?>

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo $url_to_load; ?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

I think this is a little bit more elegant since it avoids switch statements and uses hash tables implemented through PHP associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me like this:

```
<?php
$monday = "rnPkmozi7Zc";
$tuesday = "rnPkmozi7Zc";
$wednesday = "rnPkmozi7Zc";
$thursday = "rnPkmozi7Zc";
$friday = "rnPkmozi7Zc";
$saturday = "rnPkmozi7Zc";
$sunday  = "rnPkmozi7Zc";

$dayofweek = date("w");

switch ($dayofweek) {
    case 1:
        $videoUrl = $monday;
        break;
    case 2:
        $videoUrl = $tuesday;
        break;
    case 3:
        $videoUrl = $wednesday;
        break;
    case 4:
        $videoUrl = $thursday;
        break;
    case 5:
        $videoUrl = $friday;
        break;
    case 6:
        $videoUrl = $saturday;
        break;
    case 0:
        $videoUrl = $sunday;
        break;
}

echo '
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoUrl.'" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
';

?>
```